# Basic Networking in Linux subssequent calls to the read function

Tags: c++, c, linux, networking

I am programming in C++ in the linux environment using the `#include <sys/socket.h>` library. I am having difficulty understand the read and write functions. They are not working like I would expect, something with maybe not emptying buffers? I read the documentation on the read function and the max it can read is 65,000 some bytes. I know there has to be a way to read more and empty the buffers, etc...

I have a client server program and the client calls the write function multiple times like this...

```
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {   
        int n = write(socketFileDescriptor,"I got your message",18);
        if (n < 0) socketError("ERROR writing to socket");
    }
```

I have a server program that calls the read function multiple times like this...

```
void* run(void* arg)
{
    ServerSocket* ss = (ServerSocket*)arg;
    while(true)
    {
        char buffer[256];
        bzero(buffer,256);
        int n = read(ss->newsockfd,buffer,256);
        printf("Here is the message: %s",buffer);
    }

}
```

Instead of getting only 5 versions of the sent string, I get 25.

Here is the message: Here is the message: Here is the message: Here is the message: Here is the message: Here is the message: Here is the message: Here is the message: Here is the message: Here is the message: Here is the message: Here is the message: Here is the message: Here is the message: Here is the message: Here is the message: Here is the message: Here is the message: Here is the message: Here is the message: Here is the message: Here is the message: Here is the message: Here is the message: Here is the message: Here is the message: Here is the message: Here is the message: Here is the message: Here is the message:

Comment: Are you saying you get 25 reads, 0 bytes each? And how do you get out of the loop?

Comment: So that run method is running in a separate linux thread from the pthread library. So the purpose of that thread it to continuously read and print what is read.

Comment: From your output, it seems like your `read()` is returning 0. If it's a regular blocking socket, that means your socked has been closed. Normally you exit the loop when socket closes.

Comment: ha ha, you are right! Thank you! Let me play with it some more. -10 points for me for not having a good string to use!

Comment: Okay, so now I get all the messages in one send. So the client loops 5 times and the server only loops once and receives that message. Do you know how to flush the read/write buffers and manually send the data?

Comment: How do you mean "that message"? Does server recieve all the data in one read() call? Or does the server only receive 1/5th of the data? Care to show your new output?

Comment: On one loop of the server, it receives the same message 5 times. Here is my new output... 

MSG: I got your messageI got your messageI got your messageI got your messageI got your messageMSG: MSG: MSG: MSG:

Note: I changed the server from saying "here is your message" to simply "MSG:"

Comment: The thing about TCP is - it's stream oriented. There are no "messages" in TCP. If you need to split the stream of bytes into "messages", you need to introduce your own protocol.